# Check if a path exceeds maximum for Unix domain socket

Tags: linux, ssh, mac-osx, socket

Operating systems limit the length of a path of a Unix domain socket. How can I check whether a particular path is within that limit?

Or, to put it another way, how can I check the maximum permitted length of a path of a Unix domain socket, on a Linux or Mac OS X system?

My use case here is for SSH multiplexing: if the ControlPath is too long, then SSH multiplexing won't work since it creates a unix domain sockets. I want to be able to check for a valid control path without having to actually start an ssh session and look for the error message.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> how can I check the maximum permitted length of a path of a Unix
>   domain socket, on a Linux

On Linux, this length is usually defined as 108.

It is defined by the `UNIX_PATH_MAX` variable in the `/usr/include/linux/un.h` header file :

```
cat /usr/include/linux/un.h | grep "define UNIX_PATH_MAX"

#define UNIX_PATH_MAX   108
```

You could find further info here :

- http://www.thomasstover.com/uds.html
- http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/unix.7.html

Comment: Is there a reason why Unix socket path addresses are more limited than than PATH_MAX?

Comment: The question is if this c-struct limitiation is really enforced. Nobody forces the kernel to accept more (the c programmer in user land would have to handle it correctly). Just like the fileset bit array size from "select" is also not a kernel limit.

Answer (score 6):

On Mac OS X, According to the `unix` man page:

```
UNIX-domain addresses are variable-length filesystem pathnames of at most
104 characters.  The include file <sys/un.h> defines this address:

       struct sockaddr_un {
               u_char  sun_len;
               u_char  sun_family;
               char    sun_path[104];
       };
```

Here's a program that compiles on both Linux and OS X that will output the maximum length of the path of a unix domain socket.

```
#include <sys/un.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    struct sockaddr_un s;
    printf("%lu\n", sizeof(s.sun_path));
    return 0;
}
```

On Linux, it outputs `108`, and on OS X, it outputs `104`.

Comment: Is this true?  Is this a kernel limit? Or just an old C-style API limit like the fset size in "select" ?